# How to remove the separator and setting gear of CardboardView

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I'm trying to use CardboardView of Google sample code.

It works well.

However, there are a separator and setting gear in center of display

I want to remove them.

How can that be done?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? It's there on purpose and its placed where you can't see it when the phone is in the cardboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cardboardView.setSettingsButtonEnabled(false);
cardboardView.setAlignmentMarkerEnabled(false);
```